# Extra characters in readlines and join python? How to remove "ï»¿"? Byte Order Mark?

Tags: python, join, byte-order-mark, readlines

The python code:

```
sku_specs = "./item_specs.txt"

def item_specs():

    g = open(sku_specs,"r")
    lines = g.readlines()
    lines = "&lt;br /&gt;".join(lines)
    return lines

f = open("ouput.txt","a")
f.write("Some stuff"+item_specs()+"more stuff")
f.write("more stuff")
f.close()
```

The extra characters that show up even if the file is "blank" are `ï»¿`

When I open the file in Notepad++ and "show all symobls" I still get these BOM characters when the .txt file appears to be blank.

Related: [How do I remove ï»¿ from the beginning of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file)

Is it as simple as lines.replace("ï»¿","") ? Or is there something I am missing?

**One Solution:**

```
    lines = lines.decode("utf-8-sig")
    lines = lines.encode('utf-8','ignore')
```

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python

Comment: just as an aside you can do `return "&lt;br /&gt;".join(open(file))` to shorten up your method

Comment: Nice. Thanks. This worked. And thanks for the tip on how to code better.

Comment: @MarkRansom Your comment was the solution. If you move it to the answers I would like to mark it as such. Or is this to trivial?

Comment: I couldn't possibly take credit for a simple link.