# Removing BOM from gzip'ed CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, byte-order-mark

I'm using the following code to unzip and save a CSV file:

```
with gzip.open(filename_gz) as f:
    file = open(filename, "w");
    output = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ',')
    output.writerows(csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter = ';'))
```

Everything seems to work, except for the fact that the first characters in the file are unexpected. Googling around seems to indicate that it is due to BOM in the file.

I've read that encoding the content in utf-8-sig should fix the issue. However, adding:

```
.read().encoding('utf-8-sig')
```

to f in csv.reader fails with:

```
File "ckan_gz_datastore.py", line 16, in <module>
    output.writerows(csv.reader(f.read().encode('utf-8-sig'), dialect='excel', delimiter = ';'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 15, in encode
    return (codecs.BOM_UTF8 + codecs.utf_8_encode(input, errors)[0], len(input))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I remove the BOM and just save the content in correct utf-8?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you need to decode the file contents, not encode them.

Second, the `csv` module doesn't like unicode strings in Python 2.7, so having decoded your data you need to convert back to utf-8.

Finally, `csv.reader` is passed an iteration over the lines of the file, not a big string with linebreaks in it.

So:

```
csv.reader(f.read().decode('utf-8-sig').encode('utf-8').splitlines())
```

However, you might consider it simpler / more efficent just to remove the BOM manually:

```
def remove_bom(line):
    return line[3:] if line.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8) else line

csv.reader((remove_bom(line) for line in f), dialect = 'excel', delimiter = ';')
```

That is subtly different, since it removes a BOM from any line that starts with one, instead of just the first line. If you don't need to keep other BOMs that's OK, otherwise you can fix it with:

```
def remove_bom_from_first(iterable):
    f = iter(iterable)
    firstline = next(f, None)
    if firstline is not None:
        yield remove_bom(firstline)
        for line in f:
            yield f
```