# Converting csv to xlsx, strange out put in field headers

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm am converting .csv's to .xlsx. Everything is going well except I keep getting this  [image]

This is my code:

```
def create_workbook(my_csv):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(my_csv, 'r') as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            ws.append(row)
    wb.save(my_csv[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    f.close()
```

I am wondering if anyone has ran into something similar, and how they went about fixing it.  I am looking for something more robust than just renaming the column if possible.

Comment: Looks like a BOM. I'd try @Steve Lassop's suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899939/removing-bom-from-gziped-csv-in-python

Comment: Thank you, the csv is from a SQL output, where I manually named the Headers.  Are headers not always UTF-8  type with SQL output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more appropriate as comment -- in re: "Are headers not always UTF-8 type with SQL output?"

The csvs from "SQL" are really specific to the interface defaults you're using to generate the file.  Some scenarios:

1. If you're using an IDE that has a 'output to csv' functionality then you'll want to see how to set the properties so that the output will be encoded in the form you want (i.e. utf-8).
2. If you're using a command line in say MySQL you'll want try adding `CHARACTER SET utf8` to force the output encoding.  Might be a good idea to look at the SQL flavor docs for this one :)