# Python ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a json and get its values.
I have a folder with the JSON's archives, and I need to open all archives and get the values from them.

This is the code:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from pprint import pprint
import json
import os 
def start():
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('test'):
        for filename in filenames:
            json_file = open(os.path.join(dirname, filename)).read()
            # json_file = unicode(json_file, 'utf-8')
            json_data = json.loads(json_file)
           pprint(json_data)
            for key, value in json_data.items():
                print "KEY : ", key
                print "VALUE: ", value
                start()
```

This is one of the JSON's

```
{ "test" : "Search User 1",
   "url"  : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/1/?format=json",
   "status_code" : 200,
   "method" : "get"
}
```

But when I run it, i get this:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What the hell is wrong? Yesterday it was working exactly as it is now, or am I crazy

I tried this way:

```
from pprint import pprint
import json
import os
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('test'):
    for filename in filenames:
        json_file_contents = open(os.path.join(dirname, filename)).read()
        try:
            json_data = json.loads(json_file_contents)
        except ValueError, e:
            print e
            print "ERROR"
```

I cant see any error '-'

```
for filename in filenames:
        with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename)) as fd:
            json_data = fd.read()
            print json_data
```

This way I can see what the json files contain, but I can't use for example access by the key, like `json_data['url']`

Comment: you should rename "json_file" to "json_file_contents" or something similar. It's confusing. More important though: put a try: except ValueError around the json.loads-statement, and print out the actual contents of the file.

Comment: Is this your actual code? I'm getting an `IndentationError` on the `pprint` line.

Comment: what changed since yesterday?

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid but make sure you print each JSON before loading it. There may be at least one JSON file that is invalid.

Comment: I did a validation for each JSON I have

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible the `.read()` method is moving the cursor to the end of the file. Try:

```
for filename in filenames:
    with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename)) as fd:
        json_data = json.load(fd)
```

and see where that gets you.

This, of course, assumes you have [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/), as your example demonstrates. (Look out for trailing commas)

Comment: i didnt understand, what is fd?

Comment: it works, but now i have a string, and i cant acces the values by the keys

Comment: You're sure it's valid JSON? http://jsonlint.com/ What is the string? And my bad; try `json.load` instead of `json.loads`?

Comment: Yep, worked for me. I was doing a simple test read before parsing  text_data = file.read(data_file)    print text_data    so I could dump the source to the console and that put me at the end of the file for the json.load

Comment: `json.load` accepts a file descriptor and `json.loads` accepts a string (hence the "s"): https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 15):

For me it was an encoding problem,
you can try using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.2.html) to edit your .json file
and change the Encoding to UTF-8 without BOM.
Another thing you could check is if your json script is [valid](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this error by Converting the json file to UTF-8 with no BOM. 
Below is a python snippet and [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python) for conversion

```
myFile=open(cases2.json, 'r')
myObject=myFile.read()
u = myObject.decode('utf-8-sig')
myObject = u.encode('utf-8')
myFile.encoding
myFile.close()
myData=json.loads(myObject,'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reply suggesting that .read() was moving the cursor led to a resolution of my version of the problem.
I changed

```
print response.read()
...
json_data = json.loads(response.read())
```

to

```
responseStr = response.read()
print responseStr
...
json_data = json.loads(responseStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Trying to understand the cause, I found this issue related to `json` module:

http://bugs.python.org/issue18958

Check if the file is UTF8 encoded and if it is the case, then use `codecs` module to open and read it or just skip the BOM (byte order mark).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your ajax/$http with JSON data

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"