# Parse JSON array file python error

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a JSON file which is of the following format

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"name1",
      "age":"age1"
   },
   {  
      "name":"name2",
      "age":"age2"
   },
   {  
      "name":"name3",
      "age":"age3"
   }
]
```

When I use the JSON parser in python I am getting the following error:

```
> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Here is my code :

```
import json

with open('sample.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

print(data)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: As far as I can see, your JSON file is valid, and your code seems correct. Perhaps there's some additional, unmentioned detail?

Comment: Check for invisible characters like BOM in the file.

Comment: Check out this link... There might be encoding problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808814/python-valueerror-no-json-object-could-be-decoded