# Confusion regarding UTF8 substring length

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Can someone please help me deal with byte-order mark (*BOM*) bytes versus UTF8 characters in the first line of an XHTML file?

Using Python 3.5, I opened the XHTML file as UTF8 text:

```
inputTopicFile = open(inputFileName, "rt", encoding="utf8")
```

As shown in this hex-editor, the first line of that UTF8-encoded XHTML file begins with the three-bytes UTF8 BOM `EF BB BF`:

[image: Hex-editor view of data in a UTF8 file]

I wanted to remove the UTF8 BOM from what I supposed were equivalent to the three initial character positions `[0:2]` in the string. So I tried this:

```
firstLine = firstLine[3:]
```

Didn't work -- the characters `<?` were no longer present at the start of the resulting line.

So I did this experiment:

```
for charPos in range(0, 3):
    print("charPos {0} == {1}".format(charPos, firstLine[charPos]))
```

Which printed:

```
charPos 0 == 
charPos 1 == <
charPos 2 == ?
```

I then added `.encode` to that loop as follows:

```
for charPos in range(0, 3):
    print("charPos {0} == {1}".format(charPos, eachLine[charPos].encode('utf8')))
```

Which gave me:

```
charPos 0 == b'\xef\xbb\xbf'
charPos 1 == b'<'
charPos 2 == b'?'
```

Evidently Python 3 in some way "knows" that the 3-bytes BOM is a single unit of non-character data? Meaning that one cannot try to process the first three 8-bit bytes(?) in the line as if they were UTF8 characters?

At this point I know that I can "trick" my code into giving me with I want by specifying `firstLine = firstLine[1:]`. But it seems wrong to do it that way(?)

So what's the correct way to discard the first three BOM bytes in a UTF8 string on the way to working with only the UTF8 characters?

---

**EDIT:** The solution, per the comment made by Anthony Sottile, turned out to be as simple as using `encoding="utf-8-sig"` when I opened the source XHTML file:

```
inputTopicFile = open(inputFileName, "rt", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

That strips out the BOM. Voila!

Comment: How are you actually opening the file? Python 3 doesn't give you bytes unless you ask for them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python

Comment: @josh-lee I edited-in the file open method I used to the question. Also added a second loop that uses .encode to see what I'd get.

Comment: Try using the `utf8-sig` encoding instead (it'll remove the byte-order-marker for you)

Comment: The BOM works in part because it's an encoding of a single Unicode character (U+FEFF, ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE).  This is why Python treats it as a single character: because it *is* a single character.

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yes, thanks for that! One can but suppose that `encoding="utf-8-sig"` came into being because others have had the same problem as I. Thx 'gain...

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your edit, you can open the file with the `utf8-sig` encoding, but to answer your question of why it was behaving this way:

Python 3 distinguishes between *byte strings* (the ones with the `b` prefix) and *character strings* (without the `b` prefix), and prefers to use character strings whenever possible. A byte string works with the actual bytes; a character string works with Unicode codepoints. The BOM is a single codepoint, U+FEFF, so in a regular string Python 3 will treat it as a single character (because it *is* a single character). When you call `encode`, you turn the character string into a byte string.

Thus the results you were seeing are exactly what you should have: Python 3 does know what counts as a single character, which is all it sees until you call `encode`.