# Loading a list of dates to python 3.6

Tags: python, function, date, text

I'm using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workdays/) to add business days to a certain date.
it works just like an excel function:

```
WORKDAY(start_date,business days to add,[holidays])
```

and I would like it to read a list of holidays from a `.txt` file like this:

```
2017-09-18
2017-09-19
2017-10-09
2017-12-25
```

how can I do this? it would be easier to load it from an excel or a txt. is just fine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: from datetime import datetime
import workdays
Holidays = open("C:\holidays.txt").readlines()
print (Holidays)

friday = datetime.strptime('SEP 15 2017', '%b %d %Y')
wanted_day = workdays.workday(friday,1,Holidays)
print(friday)
print(wanted_day)

Comment: i get this: holidays =  [x for x in holidays if x.weekday() not in weekends ]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read from file.txt the dates. Once read it will add 5 workingdays to each date:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

business_days_to_add = 5
holidays = [date(year=2009,month=12,day=25)] 

for line in open("file.txt"):
    print(workday(datetime.strptime(line.strip(), "%Y-%m-%d")), business_days_to_add, holidays)
```

HTH

Comment: thank you for your help!!   but how could I turn into dates a list of string dates? i guess than when i read the txt, a string list is created. but i need it to be a date list so i can use it in the function

Comment: datetime.strptime(<string with date>, <date format>) converts a string into da datetime. In my code I read the file line by line, than for each line I convert the string (containing the date) into a datetime object.

Comment: see offical python documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: if you like my answer plase mark it as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: @ Charlie when I tried to read the txt. python reads it with and extra character at the begining. isntead of" 2017-10-01" it reads "ï»¿2017-10-01".do you have any idea of what is happening?

Comment: it is a file encoding problem. Those chars means that your file is UTF-8 encoded and it is using BOM chars at the beginning (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can strip off the BOM with a good text editor setting the encoding to utf-8 (if you are on windows you can do it with notepad++, using the encoding menu).

Comment: You can solve it also via python, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python