# Chinese character comparison returning false when it should return true

Tags: python, unicode, cjk

I am performing simple string comparison between two Chinese characters which are both properly decoded (I think) from UTF-8, however, the results are still non-equal and I haven't been able to figure out why. One character is being read from an input file and the other is from a decoded EPUB book.

**What I've tried:**

- I have decoded the file from UTF-8 and the EPUB book's content also from UTF-8.
- Read a number of posts about similar problems, but everything I could find boiled down to people not knowing how to decode the string correctly.

**The Code**

Read in the file where I get the character to compare:

```
with open(input_file_name, encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
```

In this case, the file is a single line with the character: 子

Read in the ebook and then try to find the character:

```
book = epub.read_epub(args.ebook_path)

for doc in book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT):
    content = doc.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(content)
    if word in content:
        print("MATCH FOUND")
        break
```

From the code above you can see I'm printing the content of each item in the book. Part of that output includes:

`<td class="b_cell1" width="90%"><p class="p_index_">zǐ  子</p>`

where the character clearly appears.

**What I Expected**

I expected the two characters to match. However, if I change the code to:

```
word = '子'

for doc in book.get_items_of_type(ebooklib.ITEM_DOCUMENT):
    content = doc.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(content)
    if word in content:
        print("MATCH FOUND")
        break
```

it will print MATCH FOUND and appropriately find the character. If I inspect the binary values of the character read from the file and the overwritten word shown above:

- Value of 子 from my file: b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xe5\xad\x90'
- Value of 子 as word shown in the code snippet above: b'\xe5\xad\x90'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was what is called the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding). That is what those extra three bytes (`\xef\xbb\xbf`) are on my variable.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python).

---

Simply use the "utf-8-sig" codec:

```
fp = open("file.txt")
s = fp.read()
u = s.decode("utf-8-sig")
```

That gives you a unicode string without the BOM. You can then use

```
s = u.encode("utf-8")
```

to get a normal UTF-8 encoded string back in s [a reference to the original posts' variable].