# UTF-8 Encoding in python gets transformed to ASCII?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I'm attempting to do something very simple, which is read a file in ascii or utf-8-sig and save it as utf-8. However, when I run the function below, and then do `file filename.json` in linux, it always shows the file as being ASCII. I have tried using codecs, and no luck either. The only way I can get it to work, is if I replace `utf-8` with `utf-8-sig`, BUT that gives me the issue that the file has BOM endings. I've searched around for solutions, and I found some removing the beginning characters, however,  after this is performed, the file becomes ascii again. I have tried everything her: [Convert UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 with no BOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python)

```
def file_converter(file_path):
    s = open(file_path, mode='r', encoding='ascii').read()
    open(file_path, mode='w', encoding='utf-8').write(s)
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph the `file` command.

Answer (score 3):

Files that only contain characters below U+0080 encode to *exactly the same bytes* as either ASCII or UTF-8 (this was one of the compatibility goals of UTF-8). `file` detects the file as ASCII, and it is, but it's *also* UTF-8, and will decode correctly as UTF-8 (just like any ASCII file will). So nothing at all is wrong.