# python cant parse csv as list ( utf-8 bom )

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, ads

**edit: this questions [Convert UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 with no BOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python) which only works on txt files, does not solve my issue with csv files**

I have two csv files

```
rtc_csv_file="csv_migration\\rtc-test.csv"
ads_csv_file="csv_migration\\ads-test.csv"
```

here is the ads-test.csv file (which is causing issues)
https://easyupload.io/bk1krp
the file is `UTF-8 with BOM` is what vscode bottom right corner says when i open the csv.

and I am trying to write a python function to read in every row, and convert it to a dict object.

my function works for the first file `rtc-test.csv` just fine, but for the second file `ads-test.csv` I get an error `UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM` when i use `utf-16`. so ive tried to use `utf-8` and `utf-8-sig` but it only reads in each line as a string with commas separating values. I cant split by comma because I will have column values which include commas.

my python code correctly reads in rtc-test.csv as a list of values. How can I read in ads-test.csv as a list of values when the csv is encoded using utf-8 with bom?

code:

```
rtc_csv_file="csv_migration\\rtc-test.csv"
ads_csv_file="csv_migration\\ads-test.csv"

from csv import reader
import csv

# read in csv, convert to map organized by 'id' as index root parent value
def read_csv_as_map(csv_filename, id_format, encodingVar):
    print('filename: '+csv_filename+', id_format: '+id_format+', encoding: '+encodingVar)
    dict={}
    dict['rows']={}
    try:
        with open(csv_filename, 'r', encoding=encodingVar) as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj, delimiter='\t')
            csv_cols = None
            for row in csv_reader:
                if csv_cols is None:
                    csv_cols = row 
                    dict['csv_cols']=csv_cols
                    print('csv_cols=',csv_cols)
                else:
                    row_id_val = row[csv_cols.index(str(id_format))]
                    print('row_id_val=',row_id_val)
                    dict['rows'][row_id_val] = row
        print('done')
        return dict
    except Exception as e:
        print('err=',e)
        return {}

rtc_dict = read_csv_as_map(rtc_csv_file, 'Id', 'utf-16')
ads_dict = read_csv_as_map(ads_csv_file, 'ID', 'utf-16')
```

console output:

```
filename: csv_migration\rtc-test.csv, id_format: Id, encoding: utf-16
csv_cols= ['Summary', 'Status', 'Type', 'Id', '12NC']
row_id_val= 262998
done
filename: csv_migration\ads-test.csv, id_format: ID, encoding: utf-16
err= UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM
```

if i try to use `utf-16-le` instead, i get a different error `'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x22 in position 0: truncated data`

if i try to use `utf-16-be`, i get this error: `'utf-16-be' codec can't decode byte 0x22 in position 0: truncated data`

why cant my python code read this csv file?

Comment: The file is not encoded as UTF-16, or is not encoded correctly somehow.  Can you share the first few bytes (say 10 or 12) of the file?

Comment: We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: @snakecharmerb im trying to view the file with a hex editor to get you those bytes, but in the mean time here is the problematic file: https://easyupload.io/bk1krp

Comment: My editor identifies that file as utf-8 with BOM.

Comment: What text editor do you use? VS Code displays the file encoding on the bottom right.  I'm sure other good editors do something similar.  So open your file in a good text editor to make sure you have the right encoding.

Comment: if I parse the file using my function above, with `encoding=utf-8` and `delimiter='\t'` , when i get to `for row in csv_reader:` the first result is this single string `\ufeffTitle,State,Work Item Type,ID,12NC`.  where as calling the function for rtc_csv_file gives a list of each row. Im hoping to parse the problematic ads file in a similar way, where it gets a list of each column name without me having to parse/split by a char such as comma

Comment: If your input file mixes comma-delimited rows and tab-delimited rows, it is not a well-formed CSV file. You can work around it by splitting again on comma on the rows which end up containing a single value. But this is really too vague still without a representative sample of the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV is encoded with UTF-8 (the default) instead of UTF-16, so pass that as the encoding:

```py
ads_csv_file="ads-test.csv"

from csv import reader

# read in csv, convert to map organized by 'id' as index root parent value
def read_csv_as_map(csv_filename, id_format, encodingVar):
    print('filename: '+csv_filename+', id_format: '+id_format+', encoding: '+encodingVar)
    dict={}
    dict['rows']={}
    try:
        with open(csv_filename, 'r', encoding=encodingVar) as read_obj:
            csv_reader = reader(read_obj, delimiter='\t')
            csv_cols = None
            for row in csv_reader:
                if csv_cols is None:
                    csv_cols = row
                    dict['csv_cols']=csv_cols
                    print('csv_cols=',csv_cols)
                else:
                    row_id_val = row[csv_cols.index(str(id_format))]
                    print('row_id_val=',row_id_val)
                    dict['rows'][row_id_val] = row
        print('done')
        return dict
    except Exception as e:
        print('err=',e)
        return {}

ads_dict = read_csv_as_map(ads_csv_file, 'ID', 'utf-8')  # <- updated here
```

Here's the CSV for reference:

```
Title,State,Work Item Type,ID,12NC
"453560751251 TOOL, SQ-59 CORNER CLAMP","To Do","FRUPS","6034","453560751251"
```

Comment: if I parse the file using my function above, with encoding=utf-8 and delimiter='\t' , when i get to for row in csv_reader: the first result is this single string `\ufeffTitle,State,Work Item Type,ID,12NC.` . if i call the function for rtc_csv_file gives a list of each row. Im hoping to parse the problematic ads file in a similar way, where it gets a list of each column name without me having to parse/split by a char such as comma

Comment: @POVR2 Your file is either malformed or in an encoding that's not UTF8 or UTF16. With each of these encodings I got the same result: `utf-8`, `utf-16-le`, `utf-16-be`. If you know that your file will only have commas a special character, you can just read the file as a string and split on `\n` and `,`

Comment: split on `,` comma characters might work for the col headers, but i will eventually have col values which include comma characters in description/comment fields. so I cant reliably split strings with characters. Ive tried utf-8,  and utf-8-sig, but they still just return a single string for each row, instead of separating into a list

Comment: You can use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to discard the BOM.