# This txt file is giving me weird problems

Tags: python

I have a problem with the handling of txt files, the source file is encoded 'UTF 8-WITHOUT BOM' and I tried to put many "encoding = " but I can't solve this..

Here I attach an image

[Right is the origen of file and left is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzK7K.png)

This is the code.

```py
import io
import time

result = io.open("Edificado/edificadoResultadoSinPorBlancos.txt","w")
start = time.time()
print(f"Empece en: {start}")

with io.open("Edificado/edificco.txt","r",errors="ignore") as f:
    for line in f:
        if '|' in line:
            line = line.replace("|","-")
        result.write(line)
result.close()

end = time.time()

print(f"Termine en: {end - start}")
```

(the file weighs 6gb)

Any idea how I could fix it?

[this is the coding from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HFPe.png)

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Please post everything as text and explain your problem more clearly. Also try everything on a tiny file to check if size is part of the problem

Comment: Have you tried [`utf-8-sig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898439/17200348)?

Comment: You say you tried many encoding= but your sample code doesn't have one.

Comment: @Itération122442 the problem is in the  left have another character than right result and I need the same txt file

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal yes, i tried from utf-8-sig to the same and too utf-8 to utf-8

Comment: And `utf-8-sig` to `utf-8`?

Comment: Your input file is not UTF-8.  The odd character displayed by Notepad++ is the result of a decoding error.  Try different encodings in Notepad++ until you find one where every character makes sense, then use that in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use "open" ,  io.open is an alias for "open"

```
import time

result = open("Edificado/edificadoResultadoSinPorBlancos.txt","w",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape")
start = time.time()
print(f"Empece en: {start}")

with open("Edificado/edificco.txt","r",errors="ignore",encoding='utf-8',errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    for line in f:
        if '|' in line:
            line = line.replace("|","-")
        result.write(line)
result.close()

end = time.time()

print(f"Termine en: {end - start}")
```

**updated**
Alternatively
based on mark ransoms comment

just work in binary instead

```
import time

result = open("Edificado/edificadoResultadoSinPorBlancos.txt","wb")
start = time.time()
print(f"Empece en: {start}")

with open("Edificado/edificco.txt","rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        if b'|' in line:
            line = line.replace(b"|",b"-")
        result.write(line)
result.close()

end = time.time()

print(f"Termine en: {end - start}")
```

Comment: You won't be able to use `encode` to write the file if you didn't open it in binary mode - unless you're still using Python 2.

Comment: you are right infact he could just work in binary

Comment: The whole point of adding the `encoding` option to `open` is so that you wouldn't have to worry about encoding everything by hand all the time, and it would be consistent.

Comment: in my solution... errors="surrogateescape"   usually solves any problems....

my suggestion was in case  he still faces some random problem. but his problem statement is easily solved in binary mode.. he doesnt have to bother with encoding at all.. he needs to just replace "|" with "-"  line by line... and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks!, errors = "surrogateescape" is the solution!, thanks.